# My models goes from 75kB to 150 MB when converting from onnx to tf-lite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, onnx, tflite

I a have a small onnx model (generated from pytorch) that only contains convolutions with gaussian kernels, as well as upsampling / downsampling operations. Therefore, it's a small model that's only about 75KB on disk in its onnx form.

If I convert it to tf-lite for a ~1000x1500 image input size, it remains fairly small.
However, when converting it to tf-lite for a ~3000x4000 image input size, the exported model size jumps to 150 MB !

Why is that ? Can I do something to address it ?
Thanks !

Comment: Is it an option to use the Pytorch model? Check the documentation on how to add it inside the mobile

Comment: It's not, unfortunately. I know it's possible, but we decided to not go this route.